Spacing: tikz drawing like a math relation
I'm writing a tikz library to annotate text, but it removes space around math symbols:

What is the cleanest way to solve this? (for now I use \  around the annot, but it's not great practice…)
MWE:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\NewDocumentCommand{\annot}{mm}{% Oversimplified code
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(txt.base)]
    \node[name=txt,inner sep=0pt]{#1};
    \node[name=annot,above=5mm of txt,overlay,fill=orange!50!white]{#2};
    \draw[-latex] (annot) -- (txt);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{ipsum}
\begin{document}
Annot in a \annot{normal}{What is ``normal''?} text, and to annotate a symbol $a \annot{$\equiv$}{No spacing :(} b$ compared to $a \equiv b$.
\end{document}


You can use the mechanism amsmath uses for \overset, that can distinguish binary operations and relations.
This also simplifies the input.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\annot}{mm}{% Oversimplified code
  \ifmmode\binrel@{#1}\binrel@@{\annot@{$\m@th#1$}{#2}}\else\annot@{#1}{#2}\fi
}
\newcommand{\annot@}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(txt.base)]
    \node[name=txt,inner sep=0pt]{#1};
    \node[name=annot,above=5mm of txt,overlay,fill=orange!50!white]{#2};
    \draw[-latex] (annot) -- (txt);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Annot in a \annot{normal}{What is ``normal''?} text, and to annotate a symbol
$a \annot{\equiv}{No spacing :(} b$ compared to $a \equiv b$.

\end{document}


With your unmodified code you might do
\mathrel{\annot{text}{$\equiv$}}


Great, thanks a lot!

Is it possible in your non-MWE use-case to simply include the LHS/RHS of the operator within the \annot ? In the MWE, they are roughly the same width so the arrow is still centered and the spacing is now OK.
Suggestion
\annot{$a \equiv b$}{Spacing OK :)}

Result


Ahah sure, in practice it might be inside an align environment, so this would not work.
